# How to print the calendar in reverse order in UNIX?

Tags: unix, calendar

I want to print the calendar in terminal using `cal -y` command , but in reverse order. What should I add to print the calendar from December to January?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you're satisfied with output in 1 column:

```
for m in {12..1}; do cal $m 2016; done
```

Really reversed, but probably not what you want:

```
cal -y | tac
```

Reversed in 3 columns by row of 3 months:

```
cal -y | perl -0777 -ne 's/\s*$//;@r=split /(\n(?=  +[A-Z]))/; print reverse @r';
```

And with the year still on top:

```
cal -y | perl -n0777e '
    s/\s*$//; @r=split /(\n(?= +[A-Z]))/; $y=shift @r;
    print $y,"\n",reverse @r;'
```